# Out of memory issue in gwt application

Tags: gwt, maven-2, out-of-memory, gxt, java-6

I have been trying to increase heap size max to 1440 of 4 GB ram, but still i am getting the Out of memory issue after two/three refreshes in two different browsers. I have set the **VM aruments max to :  '-Xmx1440m'**, while running **gwt:run** maven goal, but no luck. My system configuration looks as follows:

**RAM : 4 GB, build tool: Maven, GWT, Java 1.6**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add -XX:MaxPermSize=256M.
It helps at least in Eclipse.